# Is it possible to change default TimeZone in MongoDB using Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, datetime, timezone, mongoid

I have such trouble: when I'm creating object and setting some datetime It is saving database in UTC TimeZone. Here is example:

```
//showing full list of object properties 
 Grant _id: 5108ee29e6b564611400000, start_date: 2013-01-30 09:56:27 UTC
 //then showing a.start_date
 Wed, 30 Jan 2013 13:56:27 +0400
```

I tried to forbid database to use UTC. Here is mongoid.yml:

```
development:
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
  sessions:
    default:
      use_activesupport_time_zone: true
      use_utc: false
      database: test_mongoid_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
```

and in application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
```

but it doesn't work.

Can someone help with this trouble ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the timezone of your application so that ruby's date object will auto configure the dates.  MongoDB will always store time in UTC.

MongoDB has no internal knowledge of timezones.

Comment: thanks. One more question: I'm setting start_date on form to 14-00, but when it saves it - it shows me 10 - 00. Can you help me ?

Comment: @DenMed So long as your application provides your timezone your application should always show the right one. Unfortunately there is no real way to fix this within the internal showing of MongoDB :(, though it is also good because then it means you can have many apps in many timezones and they can all work from one UTC date, so it does have its upsides too

Comment: You are right, but you see it substracts 4 hours from time what I set and then showing me, that this time is right in TimeZone +4. I can't get what I should do with this!

Comment: @DenMed Hang on what do you want to do wit this? You know your application shows it correctly as you showed in the example above right? And you know MongoDB cannot use UTC? I would say just make sure your app has the right timezone, does that help?

Comment: I showed bad example. It is ok in console, but when I create it using forms - it shows wrong time. For example I create object with star time now - it substracts 4 hours and showing that it is my localtime, but it is not MINE time.

Comment: @DenMed Aha I get you now, the application is not showing it right, I'll look around for something

Comment: It is not saving it properly and I don't know why ?!    2013-01-30 10:37:00 +0400 but I put 14-37 in my form.

Comment: @DenMed it is saving it properly: 2013-01-30 10:37:00 +0400 add 4 hours onto that time and you have your local time, ISO dates come in the format of Zulu time + offset format, you can tell that your date is not truly zulu time because it does not have the Z on the end for one, so it is a timezoned date with an offset of +4 hours.

Comment: @DenMed In ruby it shows: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 13:56:27 +0400 despite having applied the tz offset simply because that offset is there but it is not applied further

Comment: I can't understand you - you telling me, that everything allright ?
I will copy you Object, that I set 14-37. And here is ouput in console.
title: "14-37", description: "14-37", start_date: 2013-01-30 06:37:00 UTC. So it sustracts time two times or what ?

Comment: @DenMed Ok I think we have got ourselves mixed up. Let us define what the database shows and what the application shows because there are like 5 or six dates flying around atm. Ok so: `2013-01-30 10:37:00 +0400` is shown by the database or the application? and `2013-01-30 06:37:00 UTC` is shown by the database or the application? Also in that last comment you set 14-37 for the other fields not the time.

Comment: One more time)
I'm creating object with start_date 14-37. And next I see, that it saving wrongly. Here is output from database :  start_date: 2013-01-30 06:37:00 UTC
In view - it showing this - Wed, 30 Jan 2013 10:37:00 +0400

Comment: @DenMed Ok yes it seems like it is working the way you want. Since the application knows that your times are actually 4 hours ahead of UTC (which is what the database WILL always store in), I am not sure what you meant by "So it sustracts time two times or what ?" but I would leave the times as they are right now, when printing out the date in the application all you wanna do is omit the offset part of the date.

Answer (score 0):

`config.time_zone` doesn't set "Server Time", that is controlled by your operating system usually.

Rails always stores your dates in UTC in the database (unless you change a different setting).

Comment: How can I change this ? It coverts data to UTC and showing me wrong date. For example: I create start_date : 14-00 and it shows me 10 - 00