# Change hour mongo [with sails]

Tags: mongodb, date, timezone, sails.js

I have got mongo allocated in Mongolab and when I save some registers in the database, I am sending a specific date, in database it is saved with 4 hours more.

How I can change this timezone?? I am using Sails

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change default TimeZone in MongoDB using Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601283/is-it-possible-to-change-default-timezone-in-mongodb-using-rails-3)

Comment: No, I am using Sails. It isn't the same no?

Comment: Also please look at the basic google search results for this: https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+change+timezone as everything immediately listed will show you how you "should" be approaching this in that you do not "change the server timezone" but you work on your "client" to make sure that your working times and UTC conversions are in balance. Store in UTC. Work with locally constructed times.

Comment: Has nothing to do with sails or any other specific language or platform