# Can I change the default time zone for mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I have a mongo db which uses options such as timestamps, which would add created at and updated at date and time of when an object is created. I would like the database to store these values and other date time variables in American/New York is this possible?

I found this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601283/is-it-possible-to-change-default-timezone-in-mongodb-using-rails-3#:~:text=You%20can%20change%20the%20timezone%20of%20your%20application,UTC.%20MongoDB%20has%20no%20internal%20knowledge%20of%20timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601283/is-it-possible-to-change-default-timezone-in-mongodb-using-rails-3#:%7E:text=You%20can%20change%20the%20timezone%20of%20your%20application,UTC.%20MongoDB%20has%20no%20internal%20knowledge%20of%20timezones).

However, this is from 5 years ago and mongo could have added this functionality since then? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just curious - are you having a specific issue with UTC? Using UTC is a very common thing, when working with databases, and removes ambiguity and inconsistencies (and related errors due to multiple time zones). Dates can be converted to other time zones when processing / displaying them. Storing in specific time zones introduces potential issues, especially when storing in multiple time zones.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you for your response. No specific issues, I understand it is ideal to store everything in UTC and manipulate the date and time on the UI or API level as required. Since the application I am working on is going to be only and always used on EST I wanted to see if this was a possibility.

Comment: Keep in mind daylinght-saving times. Using UTC is still the preferred way.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you great point!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is (still) not time zone-aware, hence there is no time zone to change. You need to manage local times in your application.